# Incoming External Email STOPPED?

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2003, permissions

Firstly, I should say that I know my way around Windows very well, I don't really know the first thing about Exchange.

We are running an [sbs2003](/questions/tagged/sbs2003) Server with [exchange](/questions/tagged/exchange). This past week, everyone sending something to any of our addresses gets an error message like the following:

5.1.0 Unknown Address Error554-'Relay Access Denied-psmtp'

I can ping sbssrv.danielsconstructioninc.com externally. I can not VPN into the server either, it never makes a connection. It is definitely running, though.  I can connect to Exchange via an account in Outlook from the internal Desktop. For what it's worth, I can send email out fine through said Exchange account. I dont know much about this type of stuff but is there a service or a group of services I can restart to see if that helps.

Below is a log that I have seen people run and post in the past so maybe this will help:

[MX Log](http://zmailer.org/cgi-bin/mxverify-cgi?DOMAIN=danielsconstructioninc.com)

Like I said I dont know much about working with exchange or SBS but any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Jason\Joe Thank you for your help.  I wanted to comment on this agian but there was no option the only option I had was to answer so that is what I did.  I  found out that are mcafee subscription ended a while back but everything was working fine except for we were getting junk mail.  I guess recently mcafee quit using google for there security services and decided to aquire and use mxlogic or something along those lines.  So my guess is postini quit running our mail through their server and we stopped getting email.  Now we have reconfigured the mx records, set up mcafee, and I am TRYING to get the firewall set up on our pix 501 box but having some issues.  It seems like the mxrecords test is going better but I get a (Backend deffered failsafe) comment at the end of the tests.  Can anyone offer some insight or maybe a like to so easy to understand liturature on how to set up the cisco pix 501.  See link below for test.

[Test](http://zmailer.org/cgi-bin/mxverify-cgi?DOMAIN=danielsconstructioninc.com)

Answer (score 3):

The PSMTP at the end indicates that the error is coming from Postini's servers, not yours. You most likely were using the Postini service but didn't pay your renewal bill.

If that's not the case, check the Postini email config and make sure your domain has been entered correctly.

Comment: Wurd.  The way it sounds is he has incoming configured through postini, and outgoing is handled directly from the Exchange server.  Checking the postini config is the first place to look.

Comment: From looking at the log, I concur. Postini's modus operandi is to disable mail flow to you when you fail to pay your renewal, rather than contact you that your renewal is due. I've seen this happen on more than a few occassions.

Comment: Ok.  That is kinda what I was wondering.  This is gonna sound stupid but what is Postini?.  Would it be a Ncafee service our would it be the place that we buy our domain name from?  Thank you for all of the help and sorry for the stupid questions

Comment: Postini (owned by Google) offers email services, such as security (spam and malware blocking and filtering), discovery, continuity, etc., etc. google.com/postini/index.html. It's notoriously difficult to contact them and they work mostly via resellers so you may have a hard time getting through to them unless you have specific contact information. What you can do in the meantime is to change your MX records so that you can get email flowing again.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look at this.  I have a couple  other questions.  First why is the connection failing at the very end, and would that be why my VPN does not work.  Also I googled mx records and it looks like in order to change them I need to log on to Network Solutions (in our case) but what part of them would I modify to get mail flowing through?

Comment: Would this also cause the VPN to stop working?  Or would it be something else that would mess up the vpn?

Comment: @Aaron - Since your email is down (and has been down for a while not), I recommend calling a consultant to figure this all out for you. Now, to answer your questions in case you decide you still want to have a go at this, your MX record should point to your firewall which should have port 25 open and redirected to your SBS server. If your VPN stopped working as well, maybe you got a new firewall or maybe your IP address changed. Beware, if you point your MX records directly to you not Postini, all viruses and spam will flow into your system. You'll be flooded, but at least you'll have email.